# Initiate oozie coordinator on old dataset

Tags: hadoop, scheduling, oozie, oozie-coordinator

How can i schedule an oozie coordinator to run today's instance only after yesterday's dataset input is available. It has to check only for one input dataset which has to be an old dataset, something like 1 day ago or 2 day ago dataset. It doesn't have to wait for today's dataset input.

I have tried using something like below, here i have used ${coord:current(-1)} inside the instance tag so that it can check for yesterday's data , but this doesn't seem to work. Even if the signal is not available for yesterday's date the job gets fired at the nominal time.

```
    <coordinator-app name="hello-coord" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
              start="2009-01-02T08:00Z" end="2009-01-04T08:00Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
             xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <datasets>
   <dataset name="din" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
            initial-instance="2009-01-02T08:00Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles">
     <uri-template>${baseFsURI}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
     <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
    </dataset>
    </datasets>
  <input-events>
     <data-in name="input" dataset="din">
            <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
     </data-in>
  </input-events>
  <action>
  <workflow>
      <app-path>${wf_app_path}</app-path>
  </workflow>
  </action>
```

Comment: Can you do a `oozie job -dryrun ..` on your job and paste the resolved values back into your original question

Comment: This is working. Actually the first instance of my coordinator  blindly started the action even after the signal was not available because the "initial-instance" tag of the dataset is not an old date. It is the same as the coord "start" value. But the next day's run triggered as expected and did not initiate the action if the previous signal is not available. And for the happy flow too it is working as expected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<dataset>` tag is used to set the folder in which the trigger file will appear.

The `<input-events>` tag provides the time from which folder parameters like `${YEAR}`, `${MONTH}` and `${DAY}` are calculated.

`<instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>` means the time given is -1 day.

Hence on the first day, that is at "2009-01-02T08:00Z", the time given to `<dataset>` is `"2009-01-01T08:00Z"` which is earlier than the `initial-instance="2009-01-02T08:00Z"`. All actions before the intial-instance are executed without waiting for the trigger file to appear.

Solution is to change `initial-instance="2009-01-01T08:00Z"`

Comment: Agreed. I guess that is what I found out that time and added a comment to my original question. BTW, thanks for clarifying it further.